# How can I make the intellisense window larger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

In VS2008 it was possible to drag the corner to enlarge the window to see more methods, are there any hidden settings in VS2010 to make this window larger?

I tried to post an image but it appears I need more rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any way to do it in VS2010 by itself. If you install the  [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) plugin, you can adjust the size of the auto-complete list, but it's not cheap.

It should be trivial to write a VS addin that would enable this feature, maybe it's something that I'll look into.